# Autogenerate cwl file from sty using cli in Windows

Tags: packages, texstudio, automation, auto-completion

I want to automatically generate .cwl files anytime the .sty package content changes, without any IDE opened.

I know how to create a folder monitor using FolderChangesView, but I have a problem with running texstudio.exe in cmd in a way that would compile .sty files into .cwl. Also, if there is any other way (apart from texstudio) I am definitely open also to those solutions.